# Need to generate document.getbyElementID's ID automatically from the html declared ID

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I have listed a table cum form in an ejs using node js MySQL query. as below,

```
<% aitems.forEach(function(item){ %>
  <tr>    
    <td>
      <div>
        <%= item.fullname %>
      </div>
      <div class="small text-muted">
        <%=  item.designation %>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" onkeyup="attendance_calculation()" id="sick_leave<%=  item.idemployee %>" name="sick_leave" placeholder="Sick Leave">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="available_sick_leave<%=  item.idemployee %>" name="available_sick_leave" value="<%=  item.available_sick_leave %>" placeholder="Sick Leave" hidden>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" onkeyup="attendance_calculation()" id="casual_leave<%=  item.idemployee %>" name="casual_leave" placeholder="casual Leave">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="available_casual_leave<%=  item.idemployee %>" name="available_casual_leave" value="<%=  item.available_casual_leave %>" placeholder="Sick Leave" hidden>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="total_work_days<%=  item.idemployee %>" name="total_work_days" value="30" placeholder="Present Days">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="overtime" placeholder="Over Time Hours">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <% }); %>
```

the id of the each input control is generated by the MySQL query data until the loop ends. the id also need to generate automatically in java script for the  below code.

```
if (document.getElementById('sick_leave').value != 0) {
  var sick_leave =
    (document.getElementById('sick_leave').value) - 1 || 0;
} else {
  var sick_leave =
    (document.getElementById('sick_leave').value) || 0;
}
if (document.getElementById('casual_leave').value != 0) {
  var casual_leave =
    (document.getElementById('casual_leave').value) - 0.5 || 0;
} else {
  var casual_leave =
    (document.getElementById('casual_leave').value) || 0;
}

var total_days = 30;
var total_work_days = parseFloat(total_days) -
  (parseFloat(sick_leave) + parseFloat(casual_leave));
document.getElementById('total_work_days').value = total_work_days;
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to dynamically generate code for problems like this.  You don't show enough of what you're trying to do to know what exactly to suggest, but usually code like this can be handled with some combination of common functions that take parameters, dynamic properties on an object, arrays of predetermined ID names, queries that examine the content of the page to decide what they have to do, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass reference for the element being updated on key up event argument and store current element id in element attribute as "data-id".

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" onkeyup="attendance_calculation(this)" data-id="<%=  item.idemployee %>" id="sick_leave<%=  item.idemployee %>" name="sick_leave" placeholder="Sick Leave">
<input type="number" class="form-control" onkeyup="attendance_calculation(this)" data-id="<%=  item.idemployee %>" id="casual_leave<%=  item.idemployee %>" name="casual_leave" placeholder="casual Leave">
```

now we can have element being updated in attendance_calculation function.

```
var attendance_calculation = function (el) {

    /* if you can use jQuery */
    var el = $(el);
    var id = el.data('id');

    /* withouth jQuery*/
    var id = el.getAttribute('data-id');

    //now we can generate input elements id
    var sick_leave = "sick_leave" + id;
    var casual_leave = "casual_leave" + id;

    ... 
    // your remaing logic... 

}
```